# Is there gluegen-natives-linux-i586.jar exists?

Tags: java, jogl

I've tried to run JOGL tutorial and got  the following message:

```
Catched FileNotFoundException: /home/.../gluegen-natives-linux-i586.jar
```

Indeed, there no such library there, but there is gluegen-**rt**-natives-linux-i586.jar
Is there the bug of JOGL and I showld link gluegen-**rt**-natives-linux-i586.jar as gluegen-natives-linux-i586.jar (it seems this works :) )???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no JAR called gluegen-natives-linux-i586.jar as far as I know, you shouldn't create such a symbolic link, you should just put gluegen**-rt**.jar into your classpath instead of gluegen.jar so that GlueGen looks for gluegen**-rt**-natives-linux-i586.jar instead of gluegen-natives-linux-i586.jar, exactly like it is indicated in absolutely all our tutorials.

Edit.: Rather ask your questions about JogAmp (JOGL, JOAL, JOCL) on [our official forum](http://forum.jogamp.org).